# Is there anyway to combine line 5-7 into one line or make it shorter overall?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I'm working on a project for my CS class and I was wondering if there was anyway to make the following code shorter or more efficient:

```
data_numb = str(input("Input Data, then press enter: "))
phone_numb = int(''.join(list(filter(str.isdigit, data_numb))))
phone_numb2 = str(phone_numb)
list1 = list(phone_numb2)
list1.insert(0, "(")
list1.insert(4, ") ")
list1.insert(8, "-")
print("".join(list1))
```

Comment: with string slicing and`str.format` ? or just divisions/modulos?

Comment: Just any way to make the code shorter.  I'm suppose to write the code in as few lines as possible.

Comment: can you change your input by a hardcoded value, and show the input & output without user interaction?

Comment: why converting to integer then to sting?

Comment: everytime I tried to change it it came out as an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could concatenate sub-strings to shorten the code:

```
print('(' + phone_numb2[:3] + ') ' + phone_numb2[3:6] + '-' + phone_numb2[6:])
```

Or with f-strings (Python 3.6 or above):

```
print(f'({phone_numb2[:3]}) {phone_numb2[3:6]}-{phone_numb2[6:]}')
```

which I find neater.

Comment: sorry I was afk... Just did!

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
data_numb = input("Input Data, then press enter: ")
p = ''.join(list(filter(str.isdigit, data_numb)))
res = '('+p[:3]+') '+p[3:6]+'-'+p[6:]
print(res)
```

by inserting by hand.

Comment: Your indexes are a bit off

Comment: Changed it, I forgot that his list got actually longer each line. :D

Comment: Using the string formatting operator `%` or the `format` method is preferable to repeated use of `+` (which creates a bunch of temporary strings).